# Enter data in the last row Datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working with DataGridView and **I would like to know how I can maintain a permanent row to enter data in that DataGridView**.
I ask this because I have a blank row at the beginning, but if I paste data, there is no row available to add more data. Then I have to add a blank one.

For example, this is my DataGridView:

[image]

And if I paste data into this data grid view, I have no more rows to add data:

[image]

So, is there any way to always keep a blank row? Because in order not to have this problem, I am adding a new row whenever I paste data.

(**DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows** is enabled)

**And is there a way to paste data always in the last row?**

Comment: **[DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows?view=netframework-4.8)**

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp of course, that is enable!

Comment: Your last row is showing information, but it isn't committed yet.  Hit the [Enter] key.

Comment: [DataGridView.EndEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding a row everytime you enter data with the event CellValueChanged, and use the code below

```
DataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```